# What is the correct java data structure and search algorithm to search a set of ip ranges for inclusion

Tags: java

Given the following list if IP address ranges.

```
LOW           HIGH
192.168.10.34 192.168.11.200
200.50.1.1    200.50.2.2
```

Assuming that iterating all the addresses within all the ranges and storing them in a HashSet will use too much memory.

So we need to maintain the ranges, which are actually just shifted numbers anyway (low and high).
How would one store the ranges in a tree and then use an efficient search to find whether or not a particular address is within the range(s).

I have looked at [RangeTree](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/92search/RangeTree.java.html), but it seems to search for points on a cartesian plane, and doesn't seem suited to my use case. [KDTree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) allows one to search nearest neighbour, and when k==2 it's basically the same as the range tree.

I would want all the matches, as there might be multiple hits.

What would work here? I am very sure this is a solved problem.

Comment: Ip addresses are just 4 Bytes, i.e. can be displayed as a 32 bit `int`. convert your ip addresses to `int`s, then simply check if `low <= someAddress && someAddress <= high`. You can even store your ranges as a `long` where the lower 32bits are used for the start of the range and the upper 32bits are used for the end of the range, then you could simply store them in a `Set<Long>`

Comment: I assume he's asking for an algorithm that's faster than checking each individual range.

Comment: yes I am, I am sure there is more efficient mechanism than a brute force linear search of every range. I also don't want to enumerate the ranges and put every address in a hash set. the search would be super fast but use too much RAM.

Comment: @Jim just for clarification, how many ranges are you talking about? Ten? Thousand? Millions?

Comment: do ranges overlap ?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker "I would want all the matches, as there might be multiple hits." So yes, they must.

Comment: @lino its more about the challenge, brute force will probably be fine, but it's not the number of ranges that matters, its the frequency with which they have to be searched, that can be thousands a second, so it is significant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) will do, assuming you have no overlapping ranges.

Simply create a `TreeMap`, keyed by the lower end of the range, with the full range as the value. Locate the range using [`floorEntry(K key)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#floorEntry-K-) and verify the value is in the range.

Example using simple `Integer` instead of `IpAddress` object, but any `Comparable` object can be used as range boundaries.

```
public final class RangeMap<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private TreeMap<T, Range<T>> map = new TreeMap<>();
    public void add(Range<T> range) {
        Entry<T, Range<T>> entry = this.map.floorEntry(range.getUpperInclusive());
        if (entry != null && entry.getValue().overlaps(range))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Overlap: " + range + " vs " + entry.getValue());
        entry = this.map.ceilingEntry(range.getLowerInclusive());
        if (entry != null && entry.getValue().overlaps(range))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Overlap: " + range + " vs " + entry.getValue());
        this.map.put(range.getLowerInclusive(), range);
    }
    public boolean contains(T value) {
        Entry<T, Range<T>> entry = this.map.floorEntry(value);
        return (entry != null && entry.getValue().contains(value));
    }
    public Range<T> get(T value) {
        Entry<T, Range<T>> entry = this.map.floorEntry(value);
        return (entry != null && entry.getValue().contains(value) ? entry.getValue() : null);
    }
}
```

```
public final class Range<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private final T lowerInclusive;
    private final T upperInclusive;
    public Range(T lowerInclusive, T upperInclusive) {
        this.lowerInclusive = lowerInclusive;
        this.upperInclusive = upperInclusive;
    }
    public T getLowerInclusive() {
        return this.lowerInclusive;
    }
    public T getUpperInclusive() {
        return this.upperInclusive;
    }
    public boolean contains(T value) {
        return (value.compareTo(this.lowerInclusive) >= 0 &&
                value.compareTo(this.upperInclusive) <= 0);
    }
    public boolean overlaps(Range<T> that) {
        return (this.lowerInclusive.compareTo(that.upperInclusive) <= 0 &&
                this.upperInclusive.compareTo(that.lowerInclusive) >= 0);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + this.lowerInclusive + "-" + this.upperInclusive + ")";
    }
}
```

*Test*

```
RangeMap<Integer> map = new RangeMap<>();
map.add(new Range<>(50, 59));
map.add(new Range<>(70, 79));
for (int i = 40; i <= 90; i += 3)
    System.out.println(i + ": " + map.contains(i));
```

*Output*

```
40: false
43: false
46: false
49: false
52: true
55: true
58: true
61: false
64: false
67: false
70: true
73: true
76: true
79: true
82: false
85: false
88: false
```

Comment: it would be nice to know what would work with overlapping ranges, but that's not really a problem anyway, as you can just split the overlaps and add them separately, so I think your solution will do the trick thanks!

Comment: @Jim Since there is no value (meaning) associated with a range, you could make the `add()` method merge the new range with existing ranges, e.g. if map contains `[5-9, 12-14]` and you add `8-12`, the result would be `[5-14]`. You can then add a `remove()` method, so removing `6-9` would result in `[5-5, 10-14]`.

Comment: @Jim Might consider renaming `RangeMap` to `Ranges` or `RangeSet`. The treemap is purely internal. From the outside, you could allow iterating the ranges by implementing `Iterable<Range<T>>` and its `iterator()` method as `return this.map.values().iterator();`, thereby making the object look like an ordered set of non-overlapping (and non-consecutive?) ranges.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding this right, you have a list of ranges, and you want to put them into a structure so that it is quick to find which ranges a given value is within.

You could create a single Binary Search Tree that stores each value that is either end of a range (along with 0.0.0.0 probably) and loop forwards through that once maintaining a set of which ranges the current value is in and setting a copy of that as the data of each node upon reaching it, and then to find the ranges a given IP is within you'd simply use a Binary Search to find the highest bound value below that, and the set associated with that value would be the set of ranges that the given IP is within.

It'd be O(n^2) memory usage (and probably O(n^2) time to construct the structure, assuming that copying takes linear time based on the size of the data being copied, which I can't remember), but a single query would be O(logn) time.

Here's an image because I feel like this isn't a great explanation:

[image: A graphical representation of the data structure]

Comment: it sounds perfect, and I read it several times, but I am still not quite understanding what it looks like... sorry.

Comment: Does the picture help? I feel like this explanation is not great.

Comment: Not really, it's not a tree?

Comment: Yeah, I realized after writing this that there doesn't even need to be a Binary Search Tree, and a simple sorted array of IP/set pairs would work just as well.  The tree structure isn't important at all, just the sortedness of the values.

Comment: ok, that's still a great suggestion - it's a good start anyway